# Is Opera's kiosk mode still supported in latest version(s)?

Tags: opera, kiosk-mode

The organization I work for has deployed the Opera web browser to many (Windows) workstations; each is using the kiosk mode. At one time, there was a very detailed help page for this feature. However, I can no longer find it. Rather, this link:

http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/

...simply takes me to the main Opera help page...

http://www.opera.com/help

Has Opera stopped supporting this feature?  Or, are they simply retooling their help documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12.14 still supports the kiosk mode.  During a transition to a new publishing system recently, this link seems to have been dropped.  Documentation has been notified and will fix the link. In the mean time, this should work: http://web.archive.org/web/20130223014915/http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/

Comment: Opera/Chromium seems to have dropped the feature, at least on OSX